# Truncate a specific table from a MySQL database using Command Line

Tags: mysql, linux, database, command-line-interface

## Goal

I'm trying to truncate one of my table in my database.

---

## Details

database name : site-local
table name : cloud_securities

---

## I've tried

```
mysql -u root -p'' -h localhost site-local -e "truncate table site-local.cloud_securities"
```

---

## Result

After enter my password, I kept getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-local.cloud_securities' at line 1

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commandline has trouble with the dashes in the db and tablenames.

You can however access the client and then send your statement, have to put the db and table in backticks.

```
mysql -u root -h localhost
truncate table `site-local`.`cloud_securities`;
```

edit: nvm, you can do it from the commandline by using backticks, but you have to escape them.

**Solution:**

```
mysql -u root -p'' -h localhost site-local -e "truncate table \`site-local\`.\`cloud_securities\`"
```

Comment: Or use single instead of double quotes, then the backticks don't need to be escaped: -e 'truncate table \`benu-local\`.\`cloud_securities\`'